# PHP: Unexpected return value in \Locale::canonicalize

Tags: php, intl

According to PHP docs: `Locale::canonicalize( string $locale )` always returns a string.

After testing the method with a few inputs, I always get a string.... except for this input

`'char(119)+char(104)+char(115)+char(100)+char(98)+char(116)+char(101)+char(115)+char(116)'`.

`Locale::canonicalize('char(119)+char(104)+char(115)+char(100)+char(98)+char(116)+char(101)+char(115)+char(116)')` returns `null`.

Why is that input special? Is this a bug in PHP or expected but undocumented output?

Here are some examples that I've tried: https://gist.github.com/marcosdsanchez/e6603148f7c2257ba37d832cc40cb8f3

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/locale.canonicalize.php

Comment: Looks like input is capped at 80 chars. Sending >80 always returns null.

Comment: And same seems to also hold for all the other functions that take `string $locale` as an argument: `getPrimaryLanguage()`, `getRegion()`, etc.

Comment: From `ext/intl/intl_data.h`: `#define INTL_MAX_LOCALE_LEN 80`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conclusion: Working as designed.

The `canonicalize()` function takes a locale string as an argument, not an arbitrary length stream of characters. The PHP source in `ext/intl/intl_data.h` defines the maximum length of a locale string to be 80 characters:

```
 #define INTL_MAX_LOCALE_LEN 80
```

The following functions use this definition and take `string $locale` as an argument, and are thus capped at this max:

```
locale_get_primary_language()
locale_get_script()
locale_get_region()
locale_get_keywords()
locale_compose()
locale_parse()
locale_get_all_variants()
locale_get_all_variants()
locale_canonicalize()
locale_accept_from_http()
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure if "working as designed" as the conclusion is correct. I'd expect an error instead of null for invalid input. Also, the documentation should mention that null is expected to be returned.

Comment: Well, there are two separate chunks of code, one named `INTL_CHECK_LOCALE_LEN` which returns null and one named `INTL_CHECK_LOCALE_LEN_OR_FAILURE` which creates a failure. Only the former is actually invoked, so it appears to be a conscious choice.

Comment: Interestingly, in each case, there is a call to the C function named `intl_error_set()` but I don't see any corresponding way to pull that error from PHP code.

Comment: Here we go: [`intl_get_error_message()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intl-get-error-message.php)

Comment: Results in: `Locale string too long, should be no longer than 80 characters: U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR`